# Contract Extension is being left to the last minute

Tags: contracts

I am a contractor and I was told my contract has been extended, but haven't signed anything yet. There are 10 days remaining until my current contract ends.

I asked the boss for the new contract 4 days ago and he mentioned that HR was being slow, but I am in a panic because there are only 10 days remaining and I haven't had any new contract to sign.

Do I push for a new contract or wait a bit longer?

Answer (score 4):

You should probably give it a few days. If the company has already confirmed that your contract has been extended that means that they're going to get it to you (assuming you have this in writing, if not then follow it up ASAP).

I'd say give it at least another 3 days and if you have no reply follow it up and just nudge them to see what's happening and whether or not it is being processed. If your boss says HR is slow that means he's already notified HR and it is likely being sorted so *hopefully* you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: I have in writing which says “Delays from HR, but ur staying”. Is it good enough?

Comment: @cookieMonster It will do for now, follow the advice in the second paragraph and you should be good. A lot of HR departments can be known for last minute work

Comment: Just to add to this, it's not unusual for contract extensions to come through at the very last second and probably nothing to worry about (I've even known them to come through _after_ the expiry of the initial contract). Unless you have had a prior extension from them which was handled differently, this is probably just how they work (and even then it can change between one extension and the next for a variety of normal reasons).

Comment: When I was contract, we never even got verbal confirmation until the the expiry date of the contract. The unwritten rule was, if no one was harping you about performance, you were being kept

Answer (score 3):

As a contractor, you should charge enough to be fine with a few weeks of unplanned holidays. You should also look for different positions say a month or six weeks from the end of the contract if no contract is signed. If your current company then says “here’s the new contract, please sign”, and you have signed elsewhere, that’s just bad luck for them.

Answer (score 1):

I've been in your shoes a couple of times, and my usual position was 'Look guys, if I don't have a contract extension within 30 days of the end date then I'm going to start looking for the next gig, as my contract requires 30 days notice.'  This usually lights a fire under managers to get this nailed down.

That's an advantage of being a contractor is that you can update your LinkedIn and start looking for the next gig without worrying about an adverse reaction from your current gig.

Seems odd that the manager is waiting on HR, as in my experience contract extensions do not require a signed piece of paper, but your situation may be different.

Good luck.